# Pass keyboard shortcut to QProcess

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc, qprocess

I'm running vlc in a QProcess to start a video capture stream.

However, when I do

```
m_process.terminate();
```

it does not terminate the vlc process, and doing

```
m_process.kill();
```

crashes the program and does not save the video file properly.

I see QProcess has a write() function, so I was thinking I could send the hotkey Ctrl+Q to the QProcess, but I can't seem to find a way to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: I've just changed the Global Shortcut for quitting on vlc to 'q' and setting `m_process.write("q");` also does not work

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I don't particularly like it because it doesn't use Qt and is os dependent.

I wrote a vbscript that takes the process PID as argument.

```
set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim Time
Time = 0
Do Until Success = True OR Time > 5000
    Success = shell.AppActivate(Wscript.Arguments(0))
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
    Time = Time + 1000
Loop
if Success = True Then
    Wscript.Echo "Found vlc"
    shell.SendKeys "^q"
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Did not find vlc"
End if
```

It also has a time limit to activate the aplicataion.

I then run it through system

```
system("cscript myScript.vbs PID")
```